# what size wire for 100 amp sub panel

Tags: electrical-panel

Im doing an addition on my raised ranch home, two floor, first is bedroom with small bathroom, second is family room, diagonal to garage.

- I need to install four recessed lights and a center fan, four outlets and two exterior motion sensor lights to second floor.
- I need to install  four outlets, a center light, light for closet, fan and light for bathroom, above mirror light, a dedicated circuit for GFI outlet in bath and GFI for exterior.
- Can I install a sub-panel in the new closet?
- Can I run cable on the perimeter of garage and what size??

I'm in CT and got a city permit to do the work (home owner's permit)

Comment: Is running a conduit to the subpanel an option?  Also, how many square feet is the existing house, how many square feet are the new additions, how many breakers control kitchen outlets, and is your cooking, hot water, clothes drying, and heat gas or electric?

Comment: **Will the closet be a clothes closet?** also I did some edits so it would format as you intended...